# Zend Framework 1.9~ and PHP 5.2.11 Compatible?

Tags: zend-framework, compatibility

I have a problem here. My Zend_Forms do not render in view script.

Via FirePHP i have spotted a lot of "Need PHP 5.3 to get value"

Could someone confirm?

What should i do if i have PHP 5.2.11?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. They are compatible. I am not aware of any features that would require 5.3.
Install XDebug or Zend Debugger to see what's wrong.

Comment: +1 - I believe there are some parts available in Zend that make use of 5.3 features, but the framework itself does not require 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

They weren't supposed to be using anything that would require PHP 5.3 until ZF2.0 (which, if you read the blogs, is due soon). Did you download the framework manually, or are you tracking it via an svn:external? If you are, you may want to do it differently as from here on in we're likely to see new code requiring 5.3 being checked in.

Comment: Neither http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Zend+Framework+2.0+Roadmap not the latest announcement at http://devzone.zend.com/article/11869-Zend-Framework-1.10.2-Released has an ETA for 2.0. Given http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Zend+Framework+Version+Lifecycle#ZendFrameworkVersionLifecycle-ProductReleases I wouldn't expect ZF2.0 before third quarter. You can track the development progress at http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/branches/development-2.0/

Comment: True - but the dev team have branched off for 2.0 and will be starting to make commits. They're actively recommending people do not point their svn:externals to the trunk any longer.